# Find the closure of $C^{1}[-1, 1]$ in the space ${(\scr{B}} [-1, 1],||•||_\infty)$

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Find the closure of $C^{1}[-1, 1]$ in the space ${(\scr{B}}[-1, 1],||•||_\infty)$

\begin{align} C^{1}[-1, 1]= &\{f:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}&: f' \text {  exists and continuous }\} \end{align}

\begin{align} {\scr{B}}[-1, 1]= &\{f:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}&: f \text { is bounded }\} \end{align}

$C^{1}[-1, 1]$ is not closed in the space $({\scr{B}}[-1, ,1],||•||_\infty)$.

Consider $C^{1}[-1, 1]$

$(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subset C^{1}[-1,1]$ defined by $f_n(t) =\sqrt{t^2 +\frac{1}{n^2}}$ $\{\forall t\in [-1, 1]\}$

Then, $(f_n) \to f $ in $({\scr{B}}[-1, 1],||•||_\infty)$.

Where, $f:[-1,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(t) =|t|$

\begin{align}||f_n - f||_\infty &=sup\{|f_n(t)-f(t)|: t\in [-1,1] \}\\
&=\frac{1}{n} \to 0 \space as\space  n\to \infty
\end{align}

Hence, $(f_n) \to f $ in $({\scr{B}}[-1, 1],||•||_\infty)$

But here, $f\notin C^1[-1,1]$

Hence, $C^1[-1, 1]$ is not closed in $({\scr{B}}[-1, 1],||•||_\infty)$.

I know $C^1[-1, 1]  \subset C[-1, 1]$(closed set)

My question : What is the smallest closed set containing $C^1[-1, 1]$ in the space $({\scr{B}}[-1, 1],||•||_\infty)$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closure is $C[-1,1]$. Any function in the closure of $C^{1}[-1,1]$ is continuous because uniform limits of continuous functions are continuous. On the other hand any continuous fucntion can be approximate uniformly by a sequence of polynomials and polynomials are in $C^{1}[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 2):

$C^1[-1, 1]  \subset C[-1, 1]$(closed set)

Hence, $\overline{C^1[-1, 1] } \subseteq C[-1, 1]$

Now we prove, $C[-1, 1]  \subseteq{\overline{ C^{1} [-1, 1]}}$

Choose, $f\in C[-1, 1]$ then by Weierstrass approximation theorem, there exists a sequence of polynomial $(p_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset {\scr{P[-1, 1]}}$ such that

$(p_n) \to f $ uniformly on $[-1, 1]$

In other words, $|| p_n -f||_{\infty} \to 0 $ as $n \to \infty $ in $(C[-1, 1],||•||_\infty)$

Hence, $\overline{C^1[-1, 1] } = C[-1, 1]$